# How to use %20 in WebService call without showing it in UITextField

Tags: mysql, ios, string, date

I am attempting to use a selected-date from date picker and implement it as the *start date* for part of my login credentials.. This date picker is integrated within **UIAlert** as the keyboard, and it is displayed in a **UITextField** in the main alert box.

```
-(void)requestStartTime

{

//create the alertview
startTimeAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sales Start:"
                                          message:nil
                                         delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                otherButtonTitles:@"Next", nil];
startTimeAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;



//create the datepicker
startTimeDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
[startTimeDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(startTimeDateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];



startTimeDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
startTimeDatePicker.maximumDate = now;


NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components: NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[comps setHour:8];
[comps setMinute:0];
[comps setSecond:0];

NSDate *dateFromComps = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps]; // current date/month/year set to 8:00am


startTimeDatePicker.date = dateFromComps;
//get the textfield provided in the plain text alertview
startTimeTextField = [startTimeAlert textFieldAtIndex:0];
//change the textfields inputView to the date picker
startTimeTextField.inputView = startTimeDatePicker;
[startTimeTextField setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
//create a date formatter to suitably show the date


startTimeDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[startTimeDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd%20HH:mm:ss"];
startTimeTextField.text = [startTimeDateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromComps];

[startTimeAlert show];
[startTimeTextField becomeFirstResponder];

self.selectedStartDate = startTimeTextField.text;
}
```

If you notice, the date format I'm using is **@"yyyy-MM-dd%20HH:mm:ss"**. I have to use this because it takes the place of a *space* character.

```
self.selectedStartDate = startTimeTextField.text;
```

selectedStartDate is my string, and startTimeTextField is where the input of my date selection is. 
Below, I will post my connection method to MYSQL using this string.

```
NSString *salesStr = @"http://";
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:host];
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:@":8080/sales.php?password="];
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:pass];
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:@"&db="];
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:db];
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:@"&sdate="];
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:selectedStartDate];
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:@"&edate="];
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:selectedEndDate];
```

This all works well for me. **My question is:** how do I use the %20 without showing it in the textfield? It just doesn't look professional and I need it to show a space instead of %20 and still function properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set date format to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" and display it in the textfield without percent escapes:

```
[startTimeDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

And when you are creating your query string use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`.

```
salesStr = [salesStr stringByAppendingString:[selectedStartDate stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```